# In pytorch forecasting, is a TimeSeriesDataSet with group_ids trained separately for each group?

Tags: pytorch, forecasting, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-forecasting

I would like to confirm if this behaviour is correct.
I'm not able to find the reference Chat-GPT is using: PyTorch Forecasting provides a simple way to group time series using the group_ids argument in the TimeSeriesDataSet class. When you group your time series, each group is trained separately, and the model makes separate predictions for each group.

https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_forecasting.data.timeseries.TimeSeriesDataSet.html